# VBA Count Number of Worksheets with Specific Name (Easy)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count the number of worksheets in my workbook, then subtract specific worksheets from the total count. What am I missing? This gives me an object error:

```
wsCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheety1").Count -
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheety2").Count
```

Comment: Why are you trying to count the number of sheets in a specific sheet ?

Comment: Im just trying to subtract "Sheety1" and "Sheety2" from the total number of sheets in this workbook

Comment: Look at the code I posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cpt = 0
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Sheety1" Or ws.Name = "Sheety2" Then
        cpt = cpt + 1 
    Else 
        'Do nothing
    End If 
Next
wsCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - cpt
```

Comment: Change "Sheety1" to your sheet's name. If it does not work then MsgBox cpt just before the last line and let me know the result